# PHP IonCube Loader Error

Tags: php

using local development ampps server. php 7.1 and apache 2.4
on ubuntu. on running php programs this is found in apache error_log

```
Cannot load the ionCube PHP Loader - it was built with configuration API320151012,NTS, whereas running engine is API320160303,NTS
```

Comment: Your IonCube Loader does not match your environment. Download a new/correct version of the loader, https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php

Comment: its 7.1 one which i have included in my php extensions same as my php version. what is this build issue?

Comment: If I remember correctly its saying Apache cannot load the Loader as it is not compiled with a compatible version of the Apache headers. i would guess `API3**2015**1012` is an apache 2,2 compatible loader and `API3**2016**0303` is saying you have Apache 2.4 running

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you are using the Loader for the wrong version of PHP. PHP 7.0 has an API version 20151012 and 7.1 has 20160303, so you are using the Loader for PHP 7.0 by mistake. Download the Loaders package again, be careful to select the Loader for PHP 7.1 and then you should be fine.